# Load balancing MPI multithreading for variable-complexity tasks or variable-speed nodes?

Tags: performance, mpi

I've written an MPI code that currently multithreads by sending equal numbers of elements from each array to a different process to do work (thus, for 6 workers, the array is broken into 6 equal parts).  What I would like to do is send small chunks only if a worker is ready to receive, and receive completed chunks without blocking future sends; this way if one chunk takes 10 seconds but the other chunks take 1 second, other data can be processed while waiting for the long chunk to complete.

Here's some skeleton code I've put together:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

struct crazytaxi
{
    double a = 10.0;
    double b = 25.2;
    double c = 222.222;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //Initial and temp kanno vectors
    std::vector<crazytaxi> kanno;
    std::vector<crazytaxi> kanno_tmp;

    //init MPI
    MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);

    //allocate vector
    int SZ = 4200;
    kanno.resize(SZ);

    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&world_size);

    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&world_rank);

    if (world_rank == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < SZ; i++)
            kanno[i].a = 1.0*i;
            kanno[i].b = 10.0/(i+1);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

        //Make sure all processes have same kanno vector;
        if (world_rank == 0) {
            for (int i = 1; i < world_size; i++)
                MPI_Send(&kanno[0],sizeof(crazytaxi)*kanno.size(),MPI_BYTE,i,3,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        } else {
            MPI_Recv(&kanno[0],sizeof(crazytaxi)*kanno.size(),MPI_BYTE,0,3,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        }

        //copy to tmp vector
        kanno_tmp = kanno;
        MPI_Barrier();

        //the sender
        if (world_rank == 0) {
            unsigned p1 = 0;
            unsigned segment = 10;
            unsigned p2 = segment;
            while (p1 < SZ) {
                for (int i = 0; i < world_size; i++) {
                    //if (process #i is ready to receive)
                        //Send data in chunks of 10 to i
                    //else
                        //continue
                }
            }
        }
        if (world_rank != 0) {
            //Receive data to be processed
            //do some math
            for (unsigned i = p1; i < p2; i++)
                kanno_tmp[i].a = std::sqrt(kanno[i].a)/((double)i+1.0);

            //Send processed data to 0 and wait to receive new data.
        }

        //copy temp vector to kanno
        kanno = kanno_tmp;
    }

    //print some of the results;
    if (world_rank == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < SZ; i += 40)
            printf("Line %d: %lg,%lg\n",i,kanno[i].a,kanno[i].b);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

I can 90% turn this into what I want, except that my MPI_Send and MPI_Recv calls will block, or the 'master' process won't know that the 'slave' processes are ready to receive data.

Is there a way in MPI to do something like

```
unsigned Datapointer = [some_array_index];
while (Datapointer < array_size) {
    if (world_rank == 0) {
        for (int i = 1; i < world_size; i++)
        {
            if (<process i is ready to receive>) {
                MPI_Send([...]);
                Datapointer += 10;
            }
            if (<process i has sent data>)
                MPI_Recv([...]);
            if (Datapointer > array_size) {
                MPI_Bcast([killswitch]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
MPI_Barrier();
```

or is there a more efficient way to structure this for variable-complexity chunks or variable-speed nodes?

Comment: The master *knows* the status of all its slaves: they are idle unless they were sent data to crunch *and* they did not sent the result back. I suggest you `MPI_Recv(..., src=MPI_ANY, ...)` and then use `status.MPI_SOURCE` in order to wait for the first available result from the fastest slave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **@Gilles Gouaillardet**, pointed out the keywords in such scenario is `MPI_ANY_SOURCE`. Using it, the processes can receive message from any source. To know which process send that message, you can use `status.MPI_SOURCE` on the status of the `recv` call.

```
MPI_Status status;
if(rank == 0) {
  //send initial work to all processes
  while(true) {
    MPI_recv(buf, 32, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    // do the distribution logic
    MPI_send(buf, 32, MPI_INT, status.MPI_SOURCE, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    // break out of the loop once the work is over and send all the processes 
    message to stop waiting for work
  }
}
else {
  while(true){
    // receive work from rank 0
    MPI_recv(buf, 32, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    // Perform computation and send back the result
    MPI_send(buf, 32, MPI_INT, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    //break this until asked by master 0 using some kind of special message
  }
}
```